# How Cake PHP pass parameters from one controller action to another view

Tags: cakephp, redirect, parameters

I have a search method in my `WorkersController.php` like following:

```
public function search() {
    $conditions = array();
    if(!empty($this->request->data)){
        foreach($this->request->data['Search'] as $field => $search_condition ) {
            if(!empty($search_condition))
                $conditions["$field LIKE "] = "%$search_condition%";
        }
    }
    if(!empty($conditions)){
        $this->Worker->recursive = 0;
        $workers = $this->Worker->find('all',array('conditions' => $conditions));
    }
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index','search' ));
}
```

IN the method I call `redirect()`, then the page goes to `index.ctp`, where I want to fetch `$workers` like this:

```
if($this->request->params['pass']==array('search')){
    if (empty($workers)){
        echo('No result found!');
    }else{
        foreach ($workers as $worker){ 
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

But I just can't fetch `$workers`, how can I pass it from `search()` to `index.ctp`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you explain the logic here a bit? Do you have a search view with a form that get posted to this search action, and you want the result to be displayed on the index?

Comment: Actually,this is my friend's project.There is a `search_worker.ctp` in the `Elements` folder,who has a form named `Search` getting posted to this search action.And in `index.ctp` there is `echo $this->element('search_worker');`. I suppose she want to show the result on the index,so I redirect to `index.ctp` and show it.I just didn't know how to pass the data to `index.ctp`,and I know it now,thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try and use Session for this case.

//in controller1
$this->Session->write('worker', $workers);

//in controller2
$workersData = $this->Session->read('worker');

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use as per below syntax to

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'workers', 'action' => 'index', 'pass' => 'param', 'pass1' => 'param1'));
```

for more detail you can use [doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html)

Comment: well,this does work,but how to if params are too long.In this case,I can pass `$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index','search' , 'conditions' => $conditions));`.How to do if not a tiny data but a huge one?